# How do you set types on getting Object.keys on JSON file in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, solidity, web3js, abi

I am trying to access an object from a JSON file and the error I am getting:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{...}'. ts(7053)
```

JSON file:

```json
"networks": {
  "5777": {
    "event": {},
    "links": {},
    "address": "string",
    "transactionHash": "string"
  }
}
```

The value `5777` will be changed from time to time. So I am trying to access the value, which gives me an error.

Snippet from TS file:

```js
import { abi, networks } from '../build/contracts/Example.json';
import Web3 from 'web3';
let networkId: any = Object.keys(networks)[0]; // 5777
new web3.eth.Contract(abi, networks[networkId].address); // causing error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast it manually

```
let networkId = Object.keys(networks)[0] as keyof typeof networks; // 5777
```

Comment: Could you please explain me what is `keyof` doing? Is it getting the keys from the JSON file and casting the type against `networks` object?

Comment: Yes, to your question. And the doc explains it well https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i upvoted the `@ABOS` answer, and in enhancement and as a detailed have mentioned following source code for `contract data` creation using `abi`

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
import ElectionCommission, { networks as ecNetworks} from "./truffle_abis/ElectionCommission.json";

let networkId = Object.keys(ecNetworks)[0] as keyof typeof ecNetworks;
let ecCommissionData = new web3.eth.Contract(ElectionCommission.abi as any, ecNetworks[networkId].address);
```

Hope this would help manyones.